# How to read csv file for which data contains double quotes and comma seperated using spark dataframe in databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm trying to read csv file using spark dataframe in databricks. The csv file contains double quoted with comma separated columns. I tried with the below code and not able to read the csv file. But if I check the file in datalake I can see the file.

The input and  output is as follows

```python
df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
     .option("header","true")\
     .option("quoteAll","true")\
     .option("escape",'"')\
     .csv("mnt/A/B/test1.csv")
```

The input file data:header:

```python
"A","B","C"
"123","dss","csc"
"124","sfs","dgs"
```

Output:

```python
"A"|"B"|"C"|
```